# How can I assign array object properties by using map() function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have class like this

```
export class CompetitionModel{
  id: number;
}

export class Competition{
  competitionNumber: number;
}
```

and

```
let  competitions1= [{id:10},{id:20},{id:30}  ];

let  competitions2: Competition[];
```

And I want to assign `CompetitionModel.id` to `Competition.competitionNumber` but using `map()` without using `for` or `foreach`.

How can I succeed this?

At the end of the map function I want `competitions2` to be equals to

```
[{competitionNumber:10},{competitionNumber:20},{competitionNumber:30}  ];
```

Comment: Why do you want it? `map()` is named because it is `mapping` items.

Comment: I downvoted, because this question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Harun Yılmaz because it has better performance compared to for.  I want to do stg like this         `matchesApiDates.competitions.map(x => x.competitionNumber)
                              = this.competitions.map(x => x.id);`

Comment: @Narm ahhaa I am sure you do not have any answer about the question:)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `map` function like this.

```
competitions2 = competitions1.map(c => ({competitionNumber: c.id}));
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-demo-qzydh8-yoqtfx?file=index.ts)

Or...

```
competitions2 = competitions1.map(c => {
  const comp = new Competition();
  comp.competitionNumber = c.id;
  return comp;
});
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-demo-qzydh8-d1wqbl?file=index.ts)

Comment: It is working crazy!! You are beast of typescript!    Thank you so much !!

Comment: :) Yup. That's the fun in programming, right?! Remember If this was useful to you, please [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) this answer for future readers and consider marking it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Happy codding.

Answer (score -2):

I don't use map for this but I'll update this post as soon as I can get an example of that. For now:

```
arr = [{id:123 ... },{id:432},{id:5}]

// finds a single result
theObject = arr.find(obj => obj.id == 5);

// return an array of all matching results
arrayOfResults = arr.filter(obj => obj.name === 'jo');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. They want to assign an attribute to a collection of objects, not filter by a criterion. Also you're mixing == and ===, just use === always

Comment: @Ben Racicot Thanks but it  is not answer for my question

Comment: That's not what I'm reading from the question. "assign CompetitionModel.id to Competition.competitionNumber" without looping. Also what would the empty `competitions2` array be for?